# Blender crashing on one specific frame every time

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

For some reason Blender keeps crashing when I try to render frame 7. It worked at least a few times before, but now it won't work at all; not even sheepit is able to render it. Here's the file https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhSD7EiTM5W-gp4EBKjmS1SbkJHtRg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is the usage of the experimental rendering that is causing the issue. The **experimental feature** implies possible bugs or crashes so don't worry about your scene not being set up accordingly.

Until the experimental features you are using are stable you can put the render engine back to **supported**. Then it renders just fine like it is supposed to.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'll have to keyframe the feature set since I use experimental solely for getting the details on the rims via a displacement map and adaptive subsurf. Thanks, I hadn't it might be the feature set simply because it worked on all other frames.